# Post method in not updating data on server

Tags: java, android

I am trying to post data and update data on the server. While posting I am getting response as success but this data is not updating on given URL. Please suggest me how this data will reflect on given URL.

```
public static ServerResponse postData(String url,
        FarmInchargeEntity farmInchargeEnt) {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    ServerResponse sr = new ServerResponse();
    farmChargeEntity = farmInchargeEnt;

    try {

        StringEntity se;
        se = new StringEntity(getRequestJson());

        // Set HTTP parameters
        httppost.setEntity(se);
        httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        httppost.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
            sr.setSuccess(true);
            sr.setResponseString(response.toString());
        } else {
            sr.setErrorMessage(response.toString());
        }

        Log.v("HttpPostResponse", "" + response.toString());

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sr;
}
```

// Method to get JSON string

```
public static String getRequestJson() {
    String r = "{" + "id" + ":" + null + "," + "surName" + ":"
            + farmChargeEntity.surName + "," + "givenName" + ":"
            + farmChargeEntity.givenName + "," + "dateOfBirth" + ":"
            + farmChargeEntity.dateOfBirth + "," + "education" + ":" + null
            + "," + "gender" + ":" + farmChargeEntity.gender + ","
            + "address" + ":" + "{" + "id" + ":" + null + "," + "addrLine1"
            + ":" + farmChargeEntity.addrLine1 + "," + "addrLine2" + ":"
            + farmChargeEntity.addrLine2 + "," + "taluk" + ":"
            + farmChargeEntity.taluk + "," + "district" + ":"
            + farmChargeEntity.district + "," + "state" + ":"
            + farmChargeEntity.state + "," + "pincode" + ":"
            + farmChargeEntity.pinCode + "," + "phoneNumber" + ":"
            + farmChargeEntity.phoneNumber + "," + "mobileNumber" + ":"
            + farmChargeEntity.mobileNumber + "," + "email" + ":"
            + farmChargeEntity.email + "," + "fax" + ":"
            + farmChargeEntity.fax + "," + "longitude" + ":"
            + farmChargeEntity.longitude + "," + "latitude" + ":"
            + farmChargeEntity.latitude + "," + "radius" + ":"
            + farmChargeEntity.radius + "}" + "," + "familyMembers" + ":"
            + farmChargeEntity.familyNumbers + "," + "startDateOfAssoc"
            + ":" + farmChargeEntity.startDateOfAssoc + ","
            + "endDateOfAssoc" + ":" + farmChargeEntity.endDateOfAssoc
            + "," + "farm" + ":" + farmChargeEntity.farmInchargeId + "}";

    return r;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think in your side its fine may be just check one time on server side because when you post data then server receive data and send response success but after that i will store in database or not just check one time on your web side server code